# Android - default strings for metric units?

Tags: android, string, metric

Are there in Android string values for the metric units? Something like

```
android.R.string.meters --> "meters" in EN / "metri" in IT
```

If not, is there a library for this? Couldn't find anything on the official docs nor on [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there in Android string values for the metric units?

There are not. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html) for available Android string values.

I couldnt find any resources for language strings neither.

I think you need to implement by yourself. However you dont need a library for achieving multiple language support. You can see this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) on android-developers.